# swf can not interact with API external server

Tags: flash, adobe, desktop-application

When I open swf file in Adobe Flash, It will call the endpoint from the local server (Jboss). But when I changed it to the external endpoint, It does not work. I think this issue is related to Cross domain issue. But I am not sure. If someone have any ideas, I am appreciate.

Comment: Please elaborate on *open swf file in Adobe Flash*. **Adobe Flash** is a technology, so you refer to **StandAlone Flash Player**, or **Flash Plugin** for browsers, or **Flash IDE**, or something else. Also, explain, how do you know that *external endpoint* is actually available from where you run your application.

Comment: Thanks. The external endpoint can be tested via browsers.